# Swift Firebase: "_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying our Firebase for the first time. I have chosen to install the SDK manually as **Pod Install** was taking forever.

I followed the directions step by step and when I tried to run the project I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      -[GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher initWithRequest:configuration:] in GoogleNetworkingUtilities(GTMSessionFetcher.o)
      ___45+[GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher fetcherUserDefaults]_block_invoke in GoogleNetworkingUtilities(GTMSessionFetcher.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMMIMEDocument generateInputStream:length:boundary:] in GoogleNetworkingUtilities(GTMMIMEDocument.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionFetcherLogging) loggedInputStreamForInputStream:] in GoogleNetworkingUtilities(GTMSessionFetcherLogging.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionFetcherLogging) loggedStreamProviderForStreamProvider:] in GoogleNetworkingUtilities(GTMSessionFetcherLogging.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAppAssociationRegistration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
  "_kFIRAppDeleteNotification", referenced from:
      ___15+[FIRAuth load]_block_invoke in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
  "_kFIRAppNameKey", referenced from:
      ___15+[FIRAuth load]_block_invoke_2 in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
      ___15+[FIRAuth load]_block_invoke_4 in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
  "_kFIRAppReadyToConfigureSDKNotification", referenced from:
      ___15+[FIRAuth load]_block_invoke in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuth_70be5a6d79de0ee5c6b8ffda807589e3.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I have the same problem, @JamesG Did you found any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

I can not say for sure that it isn't something else like bandwidth, but try the following out and see if it runs faster on the fresh setup/install:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you adde the `-ObjC` linker flag in your "Other Linker Settings", to force categories to be loaded. Without that, sometimes files with only categories don't get linked in properly.

Comment: Can you add the list of which frameworks you have added to your project?